# Update value when value is selected in Ember.Select

Tags: ember.js, ember.select

I have a Ember.Select in my template and an image:

```
Difficulty: {{view Ember.Select id="id_diff" contentBinding="difficulties" optionValuePath="content.id" optionLabelPath="content.title"}}
<img src="(path)" />
```

The Select is filled with values coming from server; in the controller:

```
difficulties: function() {
    return this.get('store').find('difficulty');
}.property()
```

and the model:

```
Gmcontrolpanel.Difficulty = DS.Model.extend({
    title: DS.attr('string'),
    description: DS.attr('string'),
    path: DS.attr('string')
});
```

And that's ok; but i would like that when a difficulty is selected from the Ember.Select, the corrispondent path property would be inserted in the img tag
Anyone knows how to get this result?

Comment: Could you put together a jsBin or jsFiddle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To accomplish this, I would set up a couple of things.

First, update your Ember.Select to include a valueBinding against the model with a new property:

```
{{view Ember.Select id="id_diff" contentBinding="difficulties" optionValuePath="content.id" optionLabelPath="content.title" valueBinding="selectedDificulty"}}
```

This will bind your select view to a model object.  Which means, on the controller, we can now include a new function with a .observes on that field:

```
updateImage : function(){
    this.set('fullPath', this.get('path') + this.get('selectedDificulty'));
}.observes('selectedDificulty');
```

And finally, change your image path to the newly created one:

```
<img src="(fullPath)"/>
```

Comment: oops.  Missed an important step.

<img {{bind-attr src=fullPath}}> to bind to the model attribute.  Otherwise it will only render once on entering the route.

Comment: Now something happens, but it's still not correct: i obtain in the src attr "undefined 1" and when i change the value in the  select, choosing the Nth value, i get undefined n in the src attr...

Comment: hard to debug further without the code.  Can you throw up a jsbin?

Comment: The `valueBinding` argument worked for me, thank you. But `Ember.Select` [documentation](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Select.html) does not mention that argument! Why? How am i supposed to learn that it works this way?